# Let it quit and continue to work

Tags: php

I am using some API that connects to my program from time to time and sends some valuable data (in XML) to it. All done via HTTP. The API requires the program to reply (return some XML) confirming the successful transaction or alerting about an error. The problem is that the program needs to download some images right after each transaction. That is, it needs to reply to the API and continue to work in order to download the images. My question is **how to return that XML to the API so that the API can quit and my program can continue to work?** (CRON is not an option.)

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP community: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#93441

```
<?php

// important to state not to keep-alive the connection
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");

ignore_user_abort(true);

ob_start();

// echo your output here

$size = ob_get_length(); // determine the size

// YOU NEED TO SEND THE SIZE IN ORDER for the browser / client to know when to stop
header("Content-Length: $size");

// flush buffered output
ob_end_flush();
flush();
ob_end_clean();

//  do your image downloads here

?>
```